# What software options are available to screen patients

Tags: diagnostics

I'm aware of a few software products that are intended for use by doctors to enter patient information (clover health for example), but a questionnaire-style website/app that would let a patient enter their symptoms and add any comments, as well as histories and allergies etc. would save a ton of valuable time.

Of course, no product will substitute a human interaction, and reviewing the entries would be important, but a product like this would save a ton of time.

If this is the wrong forum, I would appreciate being directed to a more appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Some of what you are looking for, will have been classed as "Expert Systems" or "Knowledge Based Systems" in the past.

An example of a system used for building such is [CLIPS](http://www.clipsrules.net/AboutCLIPS.html), a rule-based programming language for creating expert systems. Other langages like Prolog and LISP have also been used in the past.

This should give you some pointers to search for other appropriate products.

Also note that Neural Networks are also being used for some diagnostic systems e.g. see this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285912467_Artificial_Neural_Networks_in_Medical_Diagnosis).

Also search these forums for useful information:

- https://ai.stackexchange.com
- https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: See this too: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49105/how-to-build-a-symptom-checker-and-medical-diagnose-chat-bot